# Service Packs and CUs for SQL Server, do these patches make any changes to user database files? or just instance level binaries?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, sql-server-core

I am curious about patching on SQL Server.  Does anyone know if SPs and CUs make any changes to user database files or is it just the database engine and instance level binaries that get modified/updated?

Thanks

Comment: When you say user database files, you mean the data inside or some type of modification to the file itself? The database file is simply to support the database itself, whether its the data or log file.

Comment: Hi, yes I mean do the SPs/CUs make any changes to the contents of the user database data/log files.

Answer (score 4):

Service packs and CUs do not change user databases. What is changed is binaries and system databases. Sometimes, database that are not strictly system databases but are shipped by microsoft are changed as well via upgrade scripts (sysutility_mdw, SSISDB, distribution...)

Comment: Thanks Spaghettidba.  Part of the reason why I ask this question is we use SAN replication between our primary and DR sites and I was curious what the possible was of patching our DR site first then bring our DR disks online (just a copy of the DB files from the unpatched primary really) and run at our DR site while we patch the primary.  So basically the user DB datafiles would never have seen the patching.

Comment: IT won't affect the health of your user databases, nor will make additional steps necessary when moving back from DR to primary

Answer (score 0):

They won't perform major functional changes to user databases, but there may be internal structural changes to the databases to support bug fixes, changes in database engine functionality, etc.

If you've ever restored a backup from an older patch-level of SQL Server onto a newer one, you'll see a bunch of messages about it performing upgrade steps on the database that was restored. This same thing happens when patching SQL Server to a newer version. Thus you will *not* be able to move that upgraded database back to an older build of SQL Server.

Comment: Hi db2, How does this work then when in an availability group and patching the replica first, then switch roles (failover), then patch the former primary, now replica? as in this method of patching the user databases are not really accessible.

Comment: @user2073209 I'm not 100% sure on what happens behind the scenes, but my guess is that the database upgrade doesn't happen until you've actually done a failover to one of the servers that's been patched. Can't say for sure what happens in a situation with readable secondaries. I might have to try this out in some lab VMs, though I don't know if I have any that are behind on patches right now.